# Why is array_unique not working here?

Tags: php

I want `$allUrls` array to not contain duplicates.
I was trying to do it like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.keurmerk.info/Leden_Partners?s=&c=0&Page=".$i."");
    $pattern = "/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)(\w+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,6})(\/\w*)?/";
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $html, $urls );

    $allUrls[0][] = array_unique($urls[0]);

}  


foreach ( $allUrls[0] as $url ) {
    var_dump($url);
}
```

However that doesn't seem to work, it `$allUrls` array still has duplicates in it.
Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

var_dump output:

```
array(22) { 
    [0]=> string(29) "http://www.bootaccessoires.nl" 
    [1]=> string(26) "http://www.cookingforme.nl" 
    [2]=> string(24) "http://www.hoorbellen.nl" 
    [3]=> string(33) "http://www.100procentsportief.nl/"
    [4]=> string(27) "http://www.1000en1smaken.nl" 
    [5]=> string(33) "http://www.1001kerstpakketten.com" 
    [6]=> string(35) "http://www.1001wellnesspakketten.nl" 
    [7]=> string(25) "http://www.100parfums.nl/" 
    [8]=> string(30) "http://www.101brandblussers.nl" 
    [9]=> string(20) "http://www.10sign.nl" 
    [10]=> string(25) "http://www.123envelop.com" 
    [11]=> string(31) "http://www.123bloeddrukmeter.nl" 
    [12]=> string(21) "http://www.123Body.nl" 
    [13]=> string(29) "http://www.123damesfietsen.nl" 
    [14]=> string(28) "http://www.123drogisterij.nl" 
    [15]=> string(26) "http://www.123drukwerk.com" 
    [16]=> string(31) "http://www.123erotiekwinkel.com" 
    [17]=> string(30) "http://www.123feestpruiken.nl/" 
    [18]=> string(29) "http://www.123herenfietsen.nl" 
    [19]=> string(21) "http://www.123hout.nl" 
    [20]=> string(21) "http://www.123inkt.nl" 
    [21]=> string(31) "https://www.extremetracking.com" 
} array(22) { 
    [0]=> string(31) "http://www.schoonheidswinkel.nl" 
    [1]=> string(34) "http://www.winkelvandenostalgie.nl" 
    [2]=> string(25) "http://www.misteragri.com" 
    [3]=> string(30) "http://www.123kinderfietsen.nl" 
    [4]=> string(25) "http://www.123ledspots.nl" 
    [5]=> string(28) "http://www.123mijngordijn.nl" 
    [6]=> string(24) "http://www.123soatest.nl" 
    [7]=> string(29) "http://www.123sportfietsen.nl" 
    [8]=> string(27) "http://www.123superfoods.nl" 
    [9]=> string(25) "http://www.123telefoon.nl" 
    [10]=> string(25) "http://www.123tuinleds.nl" 
    [11]=> string(28) "http://www.123voetmassage.nl"
    [12]=> string(21) "http://www.12cook.com"
    [13]=> string(23) "http://www.1gameshop.be" 
    [14]=> string(23) "http://www.24parfums.nl" 
    [15]=> string(27) "http://www.2wielerwinkel.nl" 
    [16]=> string(25) "http://www.4activekidz.nl"
    [17]=> string(25) "http://www.4kidsathome.nl" 
    [18]=> string(28) "http://www.4kidsnederland.nl" 
    [19]=> string(24) "http://www.4moregames.nl" 
    [20]=> string(23) "http://www.4sporters.nl" 
    [21]=> string(31) "https://www.extremetracking.com" 
} array(19) {
   [0]=> string(27) "http://www.springtouwen.nl/" 
   [1]=> string(29) "http://www.vibiemmewebshop.nl" 
   [2]=> string(24) "http://www.slimestore.nl" 
   [3]=> string(24) "http://www.4yoursport.nl"
   [4]=> string(22) "http://www.4youwear.nl" 
   [5]=> string(18) "http://www.6566.eu" 
   [6]=> string(23) "http://www.aadenwijn.nl"
   [7]=> string(21) "http://www.aagifts.nl" 
   [8]=> string(27) "http://www.aanhangershop.nl" 
   [9]=> string(32) "http://www.aanhangwagendirect.nl" 
   [10]=> string(30) "http://www.aannemerskorting.nl" 
   [11]=> string(23) "http://www.abcoparts.nl" 
   [12]=> string(24) "http://www.aboutshoes.nl"
   [13]=> string(25) "http://www.accudienst.nl/"
   [14]=> string(25) "http://www.acculaptop.com"
   [15]=> string(32) "http://www.accuserviceholland.nl" 
   [16]=> string(22) "http://www.accushop.nl" 
   [17]=> string(21) "http://www.accuweb.nl" 
   [18]=> string(31) "https://www.extremetracking.com"
```

}

`https://www.extremetracking.com` appears three times in var_dump result.

Comment: `$allUrls[0][]` contains duplicates.

Comment: Can you provide the var_dump output?

Comment: print_r($html); and show output of your urls and also expected output

Comment: Dump $urls[0] before you do array_unique on it and show us what it contains

Comment: Why perform array_unique within the loop? Why not just add all urls to an array, then perform array_unique afterwards?

Comment: Ok I posted the var_drump result however it's in one line, idk how to post it in multiple lines.

Comment: Updated the post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each page /has/ to be separated, you could do something like this, which would remove anything that exists on page 1 from page 2, page 1 and 2 from page 3, etc:

```
$allUrls = array(0 => array());
for( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.keurmerk.info/Leden_Partners?s=&c=0&Page=".$i."");
    $pattern = "/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)(\w+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,6})(\/\w*)?/";
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $html, $urls );

    $allUrls[0][] = array_unique(array_filter($urls[0], function($url) use($allUrls) {
        foreach ($allUrls[0] as $all) {
            if (array_search($url, $all) !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }));
}
```

If they can all be merged, it could be done like this:

```
$allUrls = array(0 => array());
for( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.keurmerk.info/Leden_Partners?s=&c=0&Page=".$i."");
    $pattern = "/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)(\w+\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,6})(\/\w*)?/";
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $html, $urls );

    $allUrls[0] = array_merge($allUrls[0], $urls[0]);

}

$allUrls[0] = array_unique($allUrls[0]);
```